# Hot to enable PHP oauth in windows, Got error in "oauth.dsp"

Tags: php, oauth, pear, pecl, laragon

I try to install oauth in windows. but not properly configured.

i am using laragon php 7.0. i also tried dll paste to ext folder but i not working, after that i tried install via pear but it's also problem to install.

> pear install pecl/oauth-1.2.3
>   downloading oauth-1.2.3.tgz ...
>   Starting to download oauth-1.2.3.tgz (45,5
>   .............done: 45,531 bytes
>   6 source files, building
>   ERROR: The DSP oauth.dsp does not exist.

Please give a solution.

My system configuration is

> pear version
>   PEAR Version: 1.10.1
>   PHP Version: 7.0.8
>   Zend Engine Version: 3.0.0
>   Running on: Windows NT IT-SBALA 6.1 build 7601 (Windows 7 Professional Edition Service Pack 1) i586

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I find answer myself.

PEAR install is working only source format file. it not working windows.php.net file. like wampp, xampp and etc.,

windows version support dll only, but I tried dll already.

The actual mistake is versioning problem.

PHP 7.0.8 support oauth 2.0.XXX. I tried lowest version and highest version. not a correct version this is the problem.

Please use correct version to solve the problem...